# Specifying order of objects in aframe

Tags: aframe

Is there something similar to z-index of **CSS** in **aframe**?

i.e, if I have two objects in the xz plane, how do I make one overlap the other?

Answer (score 1):

There's no z-index but there's a z axis. In A-frame you're using a "right-handed coordinate system where the negative Z axis extends into the screen"

https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/position.html#value

This one helps visualize it:
https://www.evl.uic.edu/ralph/508S98/coordinates.html

So to play with the concept of z-index of two objects, you would change their z-axis position attributes:

```
<!-- front object -->
<a-entity position="0 0 -2"></a-entity>

<!-- back object -->
<a-entity position="0 0 -2.1"></a-entity>
```